Backtrader - stop and profit orders not executing if passing buy order as parent
i am placing a buy order in my next() method of strategy and in notify order after checking if it is completed i am placing two orders (profit and loss)
    def notify_order(self, order):
    """ This method is used to monitor the status of an order. """
    if order.status in [order.Submitted, order.Accepted]:
        # Order is in progress
        #logging.info(f"order is submitted {order.status} for {order.ref} with {order.created.price}")
        return

    if order.status in [order.Completed]:
        instrument_name = order.data._name
        if order.isbuy():
            logging.info(f"BUY EXECUTED at price: {order.executed.price} for {instrument_name} with size {order.executed.size} ")
            # calculating profit and loss values
            tpslData = self.calculateTpSl(self.tpsl['long_pos'], order.executed.price, order.executed.size,
                                          True)
            self.profit_order[instrument_name] = self.sell(size=order.executed.size, exectype=bt.Order.Limit, data = order.data, price=tpslData[1], parent = self.order)
            self.loss_order[instrument_name] = self.sell(size=order.executed.size, price=tpslData[0], data = order.data, exectype=bt.Order.Stop, parent = self.order)
        elif order.issell():
            logging.info(f"SELL EXECUTED at price: {order.executed.price} for {instrument_name} with size {order.executed.size}")
            if order != self.loss_order[instrument_name]:
                self.cancel(self.loss_order[instrument_name])
            if order != self.profit_order[instrument_name]:
                self.cancel(self.profit_order[instrument_name])
        else:
            logging.error(f"Not a expected order type {order.executed.value}")
    elif order.status in [order.Canceled, order.Margin, order.Rejected]:
        logging.info(f"order status is {order.status} at price:  {order.executed.price}")

but after buy order it is not placing any sell order, and it ends without any error after iterating through all candles in strategy.
if i remove the parent attribute from sell orders then it is working fine, only issue when both target profit and stop loss occur in the same candle, then two sell orders are placed.
